# Get first value from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an PHP array that has saved users steps:

```
array(
    'step_1' => 1,
    'step_2' => 1,
    'step_3' => 0,
    'step_4' => 0,
    'step_5' => 0
);
```

So, my user do step_1, and step_2, but he don't do other steps.
Now, i want to get name of first step **that he don't do**, it's "step_3" in this example.

But if array looks that:

```
 array(
    'step_1' => 1,
    'step_2' => 1,
    'step_3' => 1,
    'step_4' => 1,
    'step_5' => 0
);
```

I want to get "step_5", than i know that user don't do step_5 and i can, for exapmle redirect them to specify page. How can i get it?

Comment: Associative arrays have no order. Use of indexed arrays are recommended

Comment: @andrewsi, i haven't any idea :(

Comment: Or you can loop through the values in the array

Comment: use a `foreach` loop, and assign the first key to result variable where the current value is 0, and break.

Comment: You can use array_search or do a foreach loop then compare every item if it's 0

Comment: What if the array is  array(
    'step_1' => 1,
    'step_2' => 1,
    'step_3' => 1,
    'step_4' => 1,
    'step_5' => 1
);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

<kbd>**[See In Action](http://codepad.org/4iiqWNLk)**</kbd>

```
<?php 
$array = array(
    'step_1' => 1,
    'step_2' => 1,
    'step_3' => 1,
    'step_4' => 0,
    'step_5' => 0
);

$key = array_search(0, $array); // $key = step_4;

echo $key;
?>
```

Comment: He should `ksort($array);` first, because the keys might not be in order to begin with (depending on how the array was filled).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reset($array);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php

```
Return Values

Returns the value of the first array element, or FALSE if the array is empty.
```

Edit:

You can use `array_search(0,$array);`

That will return you the key of first found var. (step_5) in your case.

Comment: He wants to find the first missing step, not the first element in the array

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$step = array(
    'step_1' => 1,
    'step_2' => 1,
    'step_3' => 0,
    'step_4' => 0,
    'step_5' => 0
);
var_dump(__missing($step));
var_dump($step);
```

Output

```
string 'step_3' (length=6)
array
  'step_1' => int 1
  'step_2' => int 1
  'step_3' => int 1
  'step_4' => int 0
  'step_5' => int 0
```

Example 2

```
$step = array(
    'step_1' => 1,
    'step_2' => 1,
    'step_3' => 1,
    'step_4' => 1,
    'step_5' => 1
);
var_dump(__missing($step));
var_dump($step);
```

Output

```
string 'step_1' (length=6)
array
  'step_1' => int 1
  'step_2' => int 0
  'step_3' => int 0
  'step_4' => int 0
  'step_5' => int 0
```

Function used

```
function __missing(&$array) {
    $left = array_filter($array, function ($var) {
        return ($var == 1) ? false : true;
    });
    if (! empty($left)) {
        $key = key($left);
        $array[$key] = 1;
        return $key;
    } else {
        array_walk($array, function (&$var) {
            return $var = 0;
        });
        $key = key($array);
        $array[$key] = 1;
        return $key;
    }
}
```